# creating event via facebook graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

Is there any way to create facebook event via code (as of today), referred to the documentation :

[for v2.0](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v1.0/event)
[for v1.0](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v1.0/event)
Publishing was possible in v1.0 but not in v2.0. Is there legacy API support which I can use to create facebook events ?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your app is a Graph API v2.0 app (created after April 30th 2014), you don't have the possibility to create events anymore via the Graph API.

If your app is v1.0, the possbility to create events will vanish on May 1st 2015.

Comment: If you can't do it via the Graph API, is there any other way?

Comment: NO, other than creating the Event in the Facebook Frontend, there's no other way.